# Add a react project to a react project? or to a page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm missing up information about deployment. After running `npm run build` to my react project - i do get a build folder.

Unlike the example in React.org "like button" here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html, My component now is bigger,with many sub-components, with fetch calls... etc - it's a whole project.

In my other project, i would like to use this app, as a another part in a bigger app, to share this project between other of my projects.

is this possible?
if yes? how? if no? why? any other way?
Thank you !

--- Edit ---
Some of the other projects are not written in React. some are single page applications with jQuery. some with Backbonejs. which also does not use npm.
The option for `submodule` is applying only to the other react projects

Comment: You could take a look at deploying your app to npm and considering import it in your bigger app using npm.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible.

I think what you're looking for is to [publish package to a private npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages).

However if your project is small enough it might be easier to use [github submodules](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255).

For the most part it depends on the size and the scope for re-usability of your project. If your project is just meant to be exporting some Components/utilities that you want to use in other projects you might want to use the **private npm registry** but if you want access to the source code of the project and want it as a subset of your bigger project's repository, you might want to make use of **github submodules**.

Comment: It's a great answer! thank you!
i edited the question. some of the other projects does not use npm/node.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this. for the whole project. 
Many pages such as [React add to a website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute), reffer only to a single component. not to the whole project.

Now i know.
While developing, on the index.js we have something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyMainComponent
        someParam="something"
    />
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This code, made it running on my page. Now, to have it General, that i could use it everywhere i wrap it in a global function:

```
window.reactMyMainComponent = (params, elm) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MyMainComponent
            {...params}
        />
    , elm);
}
```

Then, i run `yarn build`

Then copy the `js` folder from `/build/static/`

Then take it to any other project, adding the 3 javascript files that are inside

Then i can call my new function `reactMyMainComponent` Anywhere, and use it when i want wherever i want :)

such as :

```
var statsBox = $(".someComp")
reactWordCloud({
    width:statsBox.width(),
    height: statsBox.height(),
    infoId:9260
}, statsBox[0])
```

Tada, now everywhere can use this :) All projects.